# how can i launch the kafka scheduler using marathon in minimesos?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, marathon, minimesos

I'm trying to launch the kafka-mesos framework scheduler using the docker container as prescribed at https://github.com/mesos/kafka/tree/master/src/docker#running-image-in-marathon using the Marathon implementation running in minimesos (I would like to add a minimesos tag, but don't have the points). The app is registered and can be seen in the Marathon console but it remains in Waiting state and the Deployment GUI says that it is trying to ScaleApplication.

I've tried looking for /var/log files in the marathon and mesos-master containers that might show why this is happening. Initially i thought it may have been because the image was not pulled, so i added `"forcePullImage": true` to the JSON app configuration but it still waits. I've also changed the networking from HOST to BRIDGE on the assumption that this is consistent with the minimesos caveats at http://minimesos.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ .

In the mesos log i do see:
`I0106 20:07:15.259790    15 master.cpp:4967] Sending 1 offers to framework 5e1508a8-0024-4626-9e0e-5c063f3c78a9-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-575c233a-8bc3-413f-b070-505fcf138ece@172.17.0.6:39111`
`I0106 20:07:15.266100     9 master.cpp:3300] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ 5e1508a8-0024-4626-9e0e-5c063f3c78a9-O77 ] for framework 5e1508a8-0024-4626-9e0e-5c063f3c78a9-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-575c233a-8bc3-413f-b070-505fcf138ece@172.17.0.6:39111`
`I0106 20:07:15.266633     9 hierarchical.hpp:1103] Recovered ports(*):[33000-34000]; cpus(*):1; mem(*):1001; disk(*):13483 (total: ports(*):[33000-34000]; cpus(*):1; mem(*):1001; disk(*):13483, allocated: ) on slave 5e1508a8-0024-4626-9e0e-5c063f3c78a9-S0 from framework 5e1508a8-0024-4626-9e0e-5c063f3c78a9-0000`
`I0106 20:07:15.266770     9 hierarchical.hpp:1140] Framework 5e1508a8-0024-4626-9e0e-5c063f3c78a9-0000 filtered slave 5e1508a8-0024-4626-9e0e-5c063f3c78a9-S0 for 2mins`
`I0106 20:07:16.261010    11 hierarchical.hpp:1521] Filtered offer with ports(*):[33000-34000]; cpus(*):1; mem(*):1001; disk(*):13483 on slave 5e1508a8-0024-4626-9e0e-5c063f3c78a9-S0 for framework 5e1508a8-0024-4626-9e0e-5c063f3c78a9-0000`
`I0106 20:07:16.261245    11 hierarchical.hpp:1326] No resources available to allocate!`
`I0106 20:07:16.261335    11 hierarchical.hpp:1421] No inverse offers to send out!`
but I'm not sure if this is relevant since it does not correlate to the resource settings in the Kafka App config. The GUI shows that no tasks have been created.

I do have ten mesosphere/inky docker tasks running alongside the attempted Kafka deployment. This may be a configuration issue specific to the Kafka docker image. I just don't know the best way to debug it. Perhaps a case of increasing the log levels in a config file. It may be an environment variable or network setting. I'm digging into it and will update my progress, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: perhaps i should add that the Docker repository used for the mesos-kafka image is public. The image was built and pushed to DockerHub according to the instructions at https://github.com/mesos/kafka/tree/master/src/docker#running-image-in-marathon .

Comment: there is also a docker commandline to run kafka-mesos according to the instructions:    
`docker run -it -p 7000:7000 --add-host=master:192.168.99.100 batwicket/kafka-mesos ./kafka-mesos.sh scheduler --master=master:5050 --zk=master:2181 --api=http://<accessible-ip>:7000 --storage=zk:/kafka-mesos`    
but get an error:    
`2016-01-06 20:40:33,448 [main-SendThread(master:2181)] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect`    
I believe the zookeeper config is different for minimesos.

Comment: Looking at the mesos log on the master and filtering for `marathon` i see: `Processing REVIVE call for framework 7e93533d-9b6a-46f9-ab08-1e771cb7327b-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-2cb48b67-ccde-4f6d-9360-3a7c01541bab@172.17.0.6:50597
Sending 1 offers to framework 7e93533d-9b6a-46f9-ab08-1e771cb7327b-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-2cb48b67-ccde-4f6d-9360-3a7c01541bab@172.17.0.6:50597
Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ 7e93533d-9b6a-46f9-ab08-1e771cb7327b-O9 ] for framework 7e93533d-9b6a-46f9-ab08-1e771cb7327b-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-2cb48b67-ccde-4f6d-9360-3a7c01541bab@172.17.0.6:50597`.

Comment: `docker logs <marathon container id>` shows: `[2016-01-07 04:53:13,264] WARN Offer [7e93533d-9b6a-46f9-ab08-1e771cb7327b-O23]. Constraints for app [/kafka-mesos-scheduler] not satisfied.
The conflicting constraints are: [field: "hostname"
operator: LIKE
value: "master"
]`
The hostname in the offer is `0f366bef3c2a` so mesos-kafka appears to expect a name resolution that isn't present in the minimesos runtime environment.

Comment: it would seem to be a problem with the kafka-mesos JSON file. The resource on offer is the id associated with one of the mesos slaves. If i remove the constraint line in the JSON file it launches.

Comment: Regrettably the scheduler fails shortly after it starts running and a TASK_FAILED appears in the slave's docker log. There doesn't seem to be any further information. I've changed the command to `./kafka-mesos.sh scheduler --master=192.168.99.100:5050 --zk=master:2181 --api=http://master:7000 --storage=zk:/kafka-mesos` and I'm using BRIDGE networking on the, possibly incorrect, assumption that HOST will not work in minimesos.

Comment: A clue may lie in the stdout/stderr of the sandbox used to run the kafka scheduler. Unfortunately i get an error when i try to access the sandbox from the mesos console: `Failed to connect to slave '7e93533d-9b6a-46f9-ab08-1e771cb7327b-S0' on '0f366bef3c2a:5051'.
Potential reasons:
The slave's hostname, '0f366bef3c2a', is not accessible from your network
The slave's port, '5051', is not accessible from your network
The slave timed out or went offline`. A job for tomorrow.

Comment: Modified the JSON to remove all mention of 'model' : `"cmd": "./kafka-mesos.sh scheduler --master=192.168.99.100:5050 --zk=192.168.99.100:2181 --api=http://192.168.99.100:7000 --storage=zk:/kafka-mesos"`. The task status is still updated to TASK_FAILED without any obvious reason in the mesos-master docker log.

Comment: Looking at `https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/minimesos-docker/blob/master/master/Dockerfile`, the only option passed to the mesos-slave seems to be `--no-hostname_lookup`. No `log_dir` is specified so, according to the docs, only stderr is written.

Comment: that said, the stderr/stdout files are present on the mesos-slave under /tmp/mesos/slaves/... There is an exception "Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 3" which causes the Executor to send a TASK_FAILED status.

Comment: thought it might be missing the LIBPROCESS_IP environment variable, as stated in the minimesos docs. If i set the variable to the IP returned by `docker-machine ip default` it says it "Failed to bind on <ip address>:0: Cannot assign requested address". If i set the variable to `$(ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | head -n 1)` it fails trying to "parse the IP".

Comment: Got it working on playa mesos by subbing in the mesos master IP address into the cmd line in the JSON file. As explained above, minimesos has problems with this. It would be Nice to get minimesos working - a quick Docker solution is best for TDD.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying this out! I am looking into this and you can follow progress on this issue at https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/minimesos/issues/188 and https://github.com/mesos/kafka/issues/172

Comment: It would be great if you could update this answer at some point in the future when the issue is completed. Just for the benefit of people who find this question on SO :)

Comment: will do.. I think it's just a question of when they get time to implement the feature or find/suggest how to properly set LIBPROCESS_IP. The minimesos project is essentially a shell on top of docker to start/stop master/slave/marathon/zookeeper containers in a batch. You can do something similar with https://medium.com/@gargar454/deploy-a-mesos-cluster-with-7-commands-using-docker-57951e020586#.vkh1n6hym if blocked.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I got Mesos Kafka installed on minimesos via a quickstart shell script. See this PR on Mesos Kafka https://github.com/mesos/kafka/pull/183

It does not use Marathon and the minimesos install command yet. That is the next step.

Comment: thanks for the update, Frank. I've been rather busy on other matters but will come back to it.